# Babylonian Operations Not Working Out So Well

Tags: exponentiation, number-systems

I'm going to denote 1 as v and 10 as < to replace the Babylonian symbols

my homework says to evaluate
$$(vv)+(<vvvv)+(<vv+vv)+(<<v)+(vv)$$
Because Babylonians used powers of 60 for their place values, I started off with
$$(2\times60^4)+(14\times60^3)+(14\times60^2)+(21\times60^1)+(2\times60^0)$$
adding everything up, I get $28,995,122$. However, my homework says the answer is $16,514$. Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the exercise? I suspect what you notate as $+$ are not all intended to mean addition...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddcjv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task as given in your image is

```
vv <vvvv <vv + vv <<v vv
```

You have inserted additional parentheses and plus signs that make it into nonsense. What is meant must be

```
2,14,12 + 2,21,2
```

which we can add with the usual pencil-and-paper addition, in base 60:

```
   2  14  12
+  2  21   2
------------
   4  35  14
```

with not even any carries. Then all that remains is to convert 4,35,14 into decimal:

$$ 4\cdot 3600 + 35\cdot 60 + 14 = 16514 $$

Comment: I don't know why you wrote 13 instead of 14, but 1 adding to 21 balanced that out. I now realized I interpreted the problem very wrongly, so I just ended up doing 
  2  14  12
+  2  21   2
------------
   4  35  14

and got the same answer. Thank you! Your answer helped a great deal

Comment: @Lex_i: Oops, that was two typos on my part that happened to cancel each other out. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

first I count 22 in your second to rightmost term.

But reversing out the book answer, it evaluates to

$2\cdot 60^3 + 14\cdot60^2 + 13\cdot 60 + 22$

And the only other thing I can guess is that something was lost in translation.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed a lot of typos in my post. The answer is apparently 16,514. I have no clue how they got this. Using the same method for similar problems i don't have any issues, but for the longer problems that go up to powers of 4 my answers are always too large